# for rails actionmailer, any way to debug ActionView::Template::Error errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In my rails 3.1 app, I do have

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

in my development.rb file (and, yes, have restarted by local dev server since changing that to true).

However, as I develop new email templates and run into the occasional ActionView::Template::Error 
I'm not seeing any of the debugging info being put out as to which line threw the error. (As opposed to when one of my normal app views has a problem the log shows the snippet of the haml source with the problem).

IS there a way to turn on similar debugging messages for mailers?

Comment: I don't know about debugging the action mailer delivery debugging...

but I use the [Letter Opener gem](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) 
to deliver the emails on development env. 

And by using this gem i'm able to see the logs if something happened during delivery (the delivery errors).... 

plus it provides a simple way to view the sent mails ( check the email style, content and so on)

If you are using vagrant for development you can get the same functionality using [Letter Opener Web gem](https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web)

Answer (score 2):

I use rails console instead of making a web request to test action mailer. It will gives a-lot more info if an error ocures.

```
$ rails c
> MyMailer::maielr_name( var1, var2 ).deliver!
```